# Mobile website zoom into images like google maps

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a mobile website and I like to insert images with an option to zoom by gesture. It should look like you zoom in on google maps, so that the other content has always the same size and only the image is zooming in. Is there any script for this? Or do I have to use iframes?

Greetz

Mik

Answer (score 1):

For the gestures part, you can use a library like hammer.js to handle pinch events.  You can find it **[HERE](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)**

For the zoom, you can use css transformation to scale an image (or div) apart from the rest of the page. In my demo below, clicking zoom in and zoom out buttons changes the CSS scale transformation value.  In your case, you would handle the pinch events and change the scale accordingly.

NOTE: Updated according to Omar's comment below.

```
<div id="imgContainer" >
    <img id="zoomImage" src="http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2003/10/soho_image_28_october_2003/10098404-2-eng-GB/SOHO_image_28_October_2003_node_full_image.jpg" />
<div>

#imgContainer{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px;
}

$(document).on("click", ".zoomBtn", function(){    
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    if (id == 'in'){
        curScale *= 1.25;
    } else {
        curScale *= 0.75
    }        
    $("#zoomImage").css({
      "transform": "scale(" + curScale  + ")"
    });
});
```

> Here is a jQM zoom image **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lufa7/3/)**

NOTE: If you are using SVG on an SVG canvas, you can scale by changing the viewport size.

Comment: nice work as always. Just one small hint, as of jQuery 1.8, it dynamically adds hooks to CSS properties, so you only need `transform` ;)

Comment: @Omar, thanks for the code review ;). That is good info and simplifies the solution. I have updated my answer accordingly.